# Include a JSP in Lotus web page

Tags: jsp, lotus-notes

is there a way to include a jsp page (what it returns) into a lotus web page ?

What I'd need is the equivalent of a

`<jsp:include url="....">`

but to use on the lotus side (a "lotus tag" if that exists)

The tag would give an HTML String back and would be used by Lotus.

Please note that I don't know anything about Lotus, this interrogation is prior to developing a project, and I'm on the JSP side :)

We will need the Lotus side to call about 1 to 10 jsp files to build the pages, but we got a technical issue at this point. The first idea was to make an Ajax call by Lotus for each of the jsp parts, but since this should also work without JavaScript, this is not a good option.

From my "JSP developer perspective", I was telling the Lotus dev to "just include my jsp's where you need them" but it looks like this can't be done that easily, therefore this question. I thought/still hope that the Lotus dev could use an easy technique to include the response of my JSP's call inside of his page

Any idea ?

Best regards,

Nils

Answer (score 0):

There is no "lotus tag" unfortunately.  Domino is designed to incorporate Lotus Notes data into web pages, but doesn't have a mechanism for easily including content from other sources into its HTTP response stream.

You could write an agent in Domino to retrieve the HTML code produced by the jsp pages, save that content into a Notes Document, and then use that document's data to produce a page in Domino.  If the content doesn't change frequently, you could consider it like using a caching system.

The other idea that comes to mind is to use IFrames in the output from Domino, and include the jsp pages within those frames.